# Coldfusion 10 cffileupload insert file name

Tags: sql, coldfusion, fileserver

```
<cfquery name="dirs" datasource="devsite" result="mySillyLittleResult">
        INSERT INTO folders (name)
        VALUES ('New Folder')
    </cfquery>

    <cfset fileId = mySillyLittleResult["GENERATEDKEY"]>

    <cfquery name="file" datasource="helloworld" result="anotherSillyLittleResult">
        INSERT INTO myfiles (id, filename)
        VALUES ('#fileId#', '#Cffile.ServerFile#')
    </cfquery>

    <cffileupload  
                    url="upload.cfm" 
                    progressbar="true" 
                    name="myupload" 
                    addButtonLabel = "Add File" 
                    clearButtonlabel = "Clear it" 
                    hideUploadButton = "false" 
                    width=600 
                    height=400 
                    title = "File Upload" 
                    maxuploadsize="20" 
                    extensionfilter="*.jpg, *.png, *.flv, *.txt" 
                    BGCOLOR="##FFFFFF" 
                    MAXFILESELECT=10 
                    UPLOADBUTTONLABEL="Upload now" align="center" />
```

Currently I am using Cffileupload to batch upload files. I am able to create INSERT SQL statements that create two new entries in a SQL database. Unfortuneately, I have been unsuccessful in determining how to also insert a file name as well. Does anyone perhaps know a way to effectively insert the file name? As you will see below, I'm using Cffile.Server ineffectively in hope of also inserting the file name into the database.  Any insight would be welcomed.

Error Code: Element SERVERFILE is undefined in CFFILE.

Comment: The error message you got means that either there is no structure named cffile or that there is, but that it doesn't contain a key named ServerFile.  A cfdump on cffile will help you troubleshoot this.

Comment: I believe it's because you're giving your file upload a name. Try referencing based on the name you've given the upload

Comment: @Matt that only pertains to the `cffile` `result="myNiftyResult"` attribute. You would use `myNiftyResult.serverFile` instead of `cffile.serverFile` `<cffileupload>` `name` attribute names the object in the client.

Answer (score 2):

`<cffileupload>` is only the form control, like `<input type = "file">`, you still need to create a handler that uses `<cffile action = "upload" (or action = "uploadall")>`. Your error is because there is no cffile structure due to no `<cffile>` tag (see [cffile docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-738f.html)).

per the [example in the cffileupload docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec18238-7fd0.html).

```
<cfif isdefined("form.FIELDNAMES")> 
      <cffile action = "upload" destination = "#ExpandPath('.')#" nameconflict="makeunique"> 
</cfif> 
<cffileupload name="myuploader">
```

There is a second example in the docs that will be more helpful. It is long winded so I'm not including it here so please read the linked docs.

you would want to put your `<cffile>` tag above your queries, like so

```
<cfif structKeyExists(form, "fieldNames")>
  <cffile action = "upload" destination = "#ExpandPath('[your upload folder]')#" nameconflict="makeunique">
  <cfquery name="dirs" datasource="devsite" result="mySillyLittleResult">
    INSERT INTO folders (name)
    VALUES ('New Folder')
  </cfquery>

  <cfset fileId = mySillyLittleResult["GENERATEDKEY"]>
  <!--- I assume it's the same database with the same data source? --->
  <!--- Changed "helloworld" to "devsite" --->
  <cfquery name="file" datasource="devsite" result="anotherSillyLittleResult">
    INSERT INTO 
      myfiles (id, 
               filename)
      VALUES (<cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#fileId#">, 
              <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#Cffile.ServerFile#">)
  </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

Comment: Actually if `fileId` is an `auto_increment` column, there is no need for quotes. But they should be using `cfqueryparam`.

Comment: indeed I thought the same thing but forgot to add it with all my other edits (of which there were several), and thanks for the extra # edit, personal pet peeve.  I answered at midnight and only one eye was working.

Answer (score -1):

To get the value of the file name, you don't use cffile.serverfile.  Try using file.serverfile.  For some reason CF defaults the object name to "file".  Don't forget to remove spaces and illegal characters from your file name.  I use [StripAllBut](http://cflib.org/udf/StripAllBut) to remove all bad characters.

Comment: That is incorrect. file has been deprecated for years. The correct name is cffile. Though these days many people opt for using the `result` attribute instead.

Comment: proof that god is fallible. :p